# Django application decomposition advice

Tags: python, django

I am a Django developer with some experience. I am familiar with different best practices and controversial points of view.

Recently, while working on one project, I struggled for a while when I came upon one giant existing app. The issue isn't resolved and I'm still in progress of thinking.

The issue itself: project has a giant application, let's name it "Directory". The application is big and serves to multiple purposes:

1) Provides basic content types for the whole project

2) Provides some helping structure entities (like, Categories, Attributes etc)

3) Handles User Area dashboard views.

4) Handles basic front-end public views.

5) Handles search.

I really don't like how big it is right now. While thinking on possible way of decomposition, I came up with multiple variants. Most likely it'll be the best to do it like this:
I can create a ***dashboard app***, a ***search app***, a ***frontend functionality app*** (serves for displaying public content).

The biggest stopper right now is the model layer. The thing is, all of the possible apps mentioned above depend literally on the same models. In my opinion, it'll be wrong to put these models to some of the apps above and leave others without models, as it'll be non-obvious where the mentioned models should live.

The possible solution, in my opinion, will be to create a separate app like "Content Types" or something like that, where I should put these models. But if I do it, I'll come up with apps that:

1) Do nothing but only provide models and admin. 2) Apps that don't have models and only provide functionality (views etc)

So, basically, I'm lost as I'm not sure that app that does nothing has a right to live separately (while the second point is more or less imaginable).

Can anyone please give me possible advice on how should I decompose my app to still follow the django-way of development and have a nice structure? I suspect that the issue I have appeared due to wrong design of the db-layer as well. But, unfortunately, it's too late to save it at the moment and I have to do my best at least with other parts.

Comment: I can't say it's the best fit for your project, but one thing I do in these cases where I know many apps will need the same core objects is to create an app called "common" or "core" that houses all the shared models, views, etc. and import them into sibling apps when I need them.

Comment: It might work, in fact. I think, I even noticed this approach a few times in different open projects. Thank you, Ivan! Still would be cool to hear other opinions as well